# Javascript output json string how to do .replace

Tags: javascript, json, object

I have this script in javascript.

```
    socket.onmessage = function (event) {
        var theDiv = document.getElementById("cli");
        var JSONObject = JSON.parse(event.data);
        if(JSONObject.event === "console output") {
            theDiv.innerHTML += "<div>" + JSONObject['args'] + "</div>";
            
        }
    };
```

the outcome of JSONObject['args'] is this:

```
>[2K [16:10:47] [Server thread/INFO]: [Server] test
```

The string is this

```
{"event":"console output","args":["\u003e\u001b[2K\r[16:10:47] [Server thread/INFO]: [Server] test"]}
```

How can i remove this from the string `\u003e\u001b[2K\r`?

i tried this but it doesn't work

```
socket.onmessage = function (event) {
        var theDiv = document.getElementById("cli");
        var JSONObject = JSON.parse(event.data.replaceAll("\u003e\u001b[2K\r", ""));
        if(JSONObject.event === "console output") {
            theDiv.innerHTML += "<div>" + JSONObject['args'] + "</div>";

        }
    };
```

How can I make it work? like this

```
{"event":"console output","args":["[16:10:47] [Server thread/INFO]: [Server] test"]}
```

Comment: Can you fix the API? Those codes are to show colors on a terminal, there's no reason to send that in an API.

Comment: No i can not fix it in the API.. but is it not possible to delete it in string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the replacement after parsing the JSON.

You need to use `map()` because `JSONObject.args` is an array.

```
theDiv.innerHTML += "<div>" + JSONObject.args.map(arg => arg.replaceAll( "\u003e\u001b[2K\r", "")) + "</div>";
```

Otherwise you need to escape all the backslashes, so they'll be treated literally.

```
var JSONObject = JSON.parse(event.data.replaceAll("\\u003e\\u001b[2K\\r", ""));
```

But it's generally a bad idea to manipulate the JSON string directly, as you may invalidate the JSON. It's usually best to parse the JSON and then deal with the resulting object/array.

Comment: No that is not working ik ge tthis error `console:53 Uncaught TypeError: JSONObject.args.replaceAll is not a function
    at WebSocket.socket.onmessage`

Comment: It's an array, so you need to map over the elements.

Comment: tnx! this is working `var JSONObject = JSON.parse(event.data.replaceAll("\\u003e\\u001b[2K\\r", ""));`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to convert `toString()` and then remove the value

```
JSONObject['args'].toString().replace('\u003e\u001b[2K\r', '')
```